# Oracle ODAC(with ODT) + VS2012

Tags: oracle, visual-studio-2010, exception, visual-studio-2012

I installed Oracle 12 ODAC(with ODT) on two computers.

I notice two things :

1. The program doesn't appear in the "Windows program list" mainly used to remove/modify installed applications (only 40MB for documentation). Bad stuff, but why not...
2. Visual Studio is not aware about the installation and when I want to add a database connection by Tools/Connect to Database...", the new Oracle providers is not showned. VS asks for at least an Oracle 7, none is registered ! Like before to install Oracle product :(

My needs are basic, I'm quite surprise the Oracle setup has a strange behavior and doesn't seem to be fully registered. 
Any idea about a missing stuff ?

Thanks by advance all, 
Nd.

PS : I need a rest tonight, I'll be back tomorrow :)

Comment: Hmm, it is weird that you have 7,8,9,10 at same time. I had 11, and  it just updated and override my 11 when i updated to 12.

Comment: Sorry Luo Sen I didn't write well. VS means I need at least one Oracle version from the 7 one. It means none is detected on the computer

Comment: Oh sorry i misunderstood your question. So i just checked, in my VS 2008 when i try to make a new connection to a Oracle Database, it only shows 7.3,8i, 9i, and 10g when I have 12 installed and using 12. However it still works, i guess it is just not reflecting there?

Comment: I can manage to access the Oracle Database by using references to the right Oracle DLL and a few lines of code. But custom tools like Petapoco or VS designer are not working. I have the same problem with VS 2010.

Comment: might it be the installation issue?

Comment: Oracle product say install is successull. Logs say everything ok :(

Comment: Oracle product say install is successull. Logs say everything ok :(

Comment: did you try uninstall everything then re-install only 12?

Answer (score 0):

I remember vaguely struggeling with the same issue. I went back to download and install the Oracle ODP.NET. That provided a setup to handle Visual studio integration and works fine for me. (Currently using ODP11.2.320)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried to install the ODP.Net. No more results. I tried to install 32 and 64 bits, both don't work. I'm gonna have to convince my boss to use SQL Server :(. I'll try a bit more before to give up, it's incredible. It's a very basic need...